# Shutdown hangs when cryptsetup try to close partition

Tags: debian, disk-encryption, lvm, sysvinit, devuan

I have two laptop with Devuan installed. When shutting down it hangs for about one minute when cryptsetup try to close the encrypted partitions.

Messages:

```
Stopping remaining crypto disks...sda5_crypt (busy)... failed.
Stopping early crypto disks...sda5_crypt (busy)... failed.
```

Partitions:

```
sda5
└─sda5_crypt
  ├─vg-root
  ├─vg-var
  ├─vg-swap_1
  ├─vg-tmp
  ├─vg-home
```

After tinkering with the scripts (`/lib/cryptsetup/cryptodisks.functions`), I know that LVM volumes are still active and I think it prevent cryptsetup from closing the partitions. If I add `dmsetup remove_all` before cryptsetup close partitions, most LVM volume are removed but vg-root remains, so it fail again.

Comment: I've got the same problem. I was using Jessie, I have upgraded to Ascii, they didn't fix the problem yet